# WCF configuration for multiple site bindings

Tags: wcf, iis-7, web-config, wcf-security

Im trying to setup my config for my WCF service correctly.

On our web server we are going to have a Service that is both accessible to Extenal internet users and Internal users.

to access the site externally you will go to http://services.ourdomain.com
to access the site internally you will go to http://servername:9090

I'd like to configure how the users are authenticated. so for external i will use a usernamevalidator and internal for now just have no authentication, but this may change in future.

how can i setup my config file that when access to the service is coming externally it will use the customvalidator but for internal it will just use regular basicHttpBinding?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your service config:

```
<services>
    <service name = "MyService">
        <endpoint address = "http://services.ourdomain.com" binding = "customBinding"/>
        <endpoint address = "http://servername:9090" binding = "basicBinding"/>
    </service>
</services>

<bindings>
    <binding name = "basicBinding">
        <security mode = "None"/>
    </binding>
    <binding name = "customBinding">
        <security mode = "Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName">
        </security>
    </binding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: If i specify 2 different address i get the following error:

"When 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/multipleSiteBindingsEnabled' is set to true in configuration, the endpoints are required to specify a relative address. If you are specifying a relative listen URI on the endpoint, then the address can be absolute. To fix this problem, specify a relative uri for endpoint"

do i need to disable multipleSiteBindingsEnabled?